# Returning an object from a function with different syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why we need to enclose the return statement `element => ({title: element.Title, rating: element.imdbRating})` in parenthesis?

```
var mappedList = filteredList.map(element => ({title: element.Title, rating: element.imdbRating}))
```

If we could just do it in this way.

```
var mappedList = filteredList.map((element) => {
  return {title: element.Title, rating: element.imdbRating}
})
```

Comment: You can do either. `()` is just shorthand for directly returning an object.

Comment: What do you mean by _“If we could just do it in this way”_? The second snippet uses an additional `return` keyword. That’s not really similar.